# How do I create 3D text in a 3D ViewPort object in a C# WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

(Sorry if this is in the wrong place. I have been bouncing around SO and Programmers SE Sites all day and I keep getting flagged. Some insight as to what I am doing wrong would be helpful). Now on to my question:

I have been following the 3D WPF C# tutorial here: http://kindohm.com/technical/WPF3DTutorial.htm all the way up to the cube demo. I am wondering if there is a way to place text on the cube either as part of the texture or as 3D text attached to the cube. If someone could point me towards a tutorial or a code snippet that would be helpful. Thanks!

Update: I forgot to mention that the one thing that I am doing differently from the tutorial is that I am embedding the WPF ViewPort control inside of a WPF UserControl inside of an ElementHost inside of a Windows Form.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial shows how to use `Material`, with a `SolidColorBrush`. Besides `SolidColorBrush` there are some more kinds of Brushes can be used with the `Material`. For example You can use `VisualBrush`, in which you can use any kind of `Visual`, including `DrawingVisual` and even `UIElement`.

Notice that if you're going to render heavy scene with a lot of texts you might encounter performance issues. `UIElement` performs very bad in 3D scene, so I would prefer using `DrawingVisual` instead. If that's still not good enough, you can rasterize your `DrawingVisual` using `RenderTargetBitmap` and then use `ImageBrush` instead of the `VisualBrush` (that's good only if the text is static - if you would like to use animations you must use the `VisualBrush` without rasterization).